# MS Access Error "The DB has been placed in a state by User..."

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, linked-list

Good morning,

when I try to paste a table from one database into another, I get the following error: "The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' on machine 'Name' that prevents it from being opened or locked". I changed the trust settings as indicated in [this article](https://www.puryear-it.com/fix-microsoft-access-restricts-database-1-user-time) to no avail.

I tested various database to see which ones would give me errors and I noticed a pattern in the error, which seems to originate only when I try to copy paste a table from databases that contain linked SharePoint lists. Doesn't matter if I try to copy/paste a linked SharePoint list or a local database table, the error stays the same.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This ,may not be related, but I've gotten this error when trying to use a linked table from a DB where I've edited the code module.  For me, saving & closing the source DB is sufficient.  Compact & repair never hurts.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "paste a table." Can you outline your steps? Migrations like this are usually a big deal, so "pasting a table" is not usually the way migrations occur unless it's coded. If you have code, please add it to your question.